# Adding a button above rendered output from a contrib module

Tags: theming

What I'm trying to do is add a button above some content that's being outputted by a contrib module (Search Api Saved Searches) .

Can I do this with hook_page_alter, if so how can I add this new render to the $page[content][system_main] .  If not what hook would be best to solve my problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: If it is a content node page then you could write page.tpl..Or If it's a form then you could alter..

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) or would like to use it, there is an area to create custom fields and display them within your node. You can use tokens and html.

Here is a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvFP16PJt4c).